# Why is the NSURLSession method "sharedSession()" called "sharedSession?"

Tags: ios, swift

What makes it "shared?" I'm taking a course in Swift iOS development, and this keeps coming up. In cursory web searches I can tell that NSURLSession.sharedSession() is the most basic use of the NSURLSession class; but that's about it. Why would the most basic variation be called "shared?"

I guess what I'm asking, is for an etymology lesson. And if you can, please explain as if to a fifth grader, as I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: Because every call to that method returns the same `NSURLSession` instance.  So everyone that calls it is sharing the same session.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation for:

```
class func sharedSession() -> NSURLSession
```

You'll see this:

> For basic requests, the URL session class provides a shared singleton
>   session object that gives you a reasonable default behavior. By using
>   the shared session, you can fetch the contents of a URL to memory with
>   just a few lines of code.

Naming conventions for singleton classes use `sharedXXXX`. This is because a singleton class is created *only* once and lives until the app killed. So, anytime you reference `NSURLSession.sharedSession()` from anywhere in your code, you're referencing the same memory blocks.